# TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' when running random Forest Classifier after text transformation

Tags: python, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to run a model using `sklearn` `pipeline` , bellow a sample of X.head() can be seen... Y  is multiclass 
My first step is a `CountVectorizer` transformation on one of the columns - `crsid_list`, 
this column is just a concatination of ids. 
the output of first step is a sparse data set.  (this step works i checked it  separately)
next step is a `RandomForestClassifier`

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier    
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('text', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3), max_df=max_df, min_df=min_df, lowercase=False),'crsid_list')], remainder='passthrough')
# second pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('model', RandomForestClassifier())])
```

[image]

when i try fitting the data 
`pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)` 
i get this:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-325-162f95e5b17f> in <module>
----> 1 pipeline.fit(x_train, y_train)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
   344             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
   345                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 346                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
   347 
   348         return self

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
   329         self.n_outputs_ = y.shape[1]
   330 
--> 331         y, expanded_class_weight = self._validate_y_class_weight(y)
   332 
   333         if getattr(y, "dtype", None) != DOUBLE or not y.flags.contiguous:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in _validate_y_class_weight(self, y)
   557 
   558     def _validate_y_class_weight(self, y):
--> 559         check_classification_targets(y)
   560 
   561         y = np.copy(y)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in check_classification_targets(y)
   178     y : array-like
   179     """
--> 180     y_type = type_of_target(y)
   181     if y_type not in ['binary', 'multiclass', 'multiclass-multioutput',
   182                       'multilabel-indicator', 'multilabel-sequences']:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\multiclass.py in type_of_target(y)
   304         return 'continuous' + suffix
   305 
--> 306     if (len(np.unique(y)) > 2) or (y.ndim >= 2 and len(y[0]) > 1):
   307         return 'multiclass' + suffix  # [1, 2, 3] or [[1., 2., 3]] or [[1, 2]]
   308     else:

<__array_function__ internals> in unique(*args, **kwargs)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in unique(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts, axis)
   260     ar = np.asanyarray(ar)
   261     if axis is None:
--> 262         ret = _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
   263         return _unpack_tuple(ret)
   264 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py in _unique1d(ar, return_index, return_inverse, return_counts)
   308         aux = ar[perm]
   309     else:
--> 310         ar.sort()
   311         aux = ar
   312     mask = np.empty(aux.shape, dtype=np.bool_)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with the target variable `y_train`. Can you check its data type?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change data types to int. Look at this code.
See data types:

```
data_type= dfj.dtypes
data_type
```

Then change types to int:

```
for col in ['COL_NAME1', 'COL_NAME2']:
dfj[col] = dfj[col].astype('int')
```